# Calling a method, and passing in a pointer to class

Tags: c++

I'm trying to call a method to add to an object to a vector within another object. I'm getting the error;

```
'': Illegal use of this type as an expression
```

Within my program I declare an object to store my node in the main;

```
accountStream *accountStore = new accountStream;
```

Then call the function;

```
new_account(&accountStore);
```

The new_account function is as;

```
void new_account(accountStream &accountStorage)
{
    newAccount *account = new newAccount;
    (&accountStorage)->pushToStore(account);
}
```

The account stream class has a vector that receives it, but there is where my error is;

```
class accountStream
{
public:
    accountStream();
    ~accountStream();

    template <class account>
    void pushToStore(account);

private:
    std::vector <newAccount*> accountStore;
};

template<class account>
inline void accountStream::pushToStore(account)
{
    accountStore.push_back(account);
}
```

The error is on the second last line;

```
accountStore.push_back(account);
```

I've got a feeling it's something to do with the way I'm passing the object into the method, but after messing around for a while I haven't been able to pinpoint where exactly I've gone wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several issues:

1. You must specify the variable name here (and not only the type):

   ```
   template<class account>
   inline void accountStream::pushToStore(account c)
   {
       accountStore.push_back(c);
   }
   ```
2. You must receive a pointer (not a reference to a pointer) here

   ```
   void new_account(accountStream *accountStorage)
   {
       newAccount *account = new newAccount;
       accountStorage->pushToStore(account);
   }
   ```
3. You must call the function with a pointer as a parameter:

   ```
   new_account(accountStore);
   ```

   Alternatively, you can declare the variable (not a pointer to):

   ```
   accountStream accountStore;
   ```

   call the function:

   ```
   new_account(accountStore);
   ```

   and receive a reference:

   ```
   void new_account(accountStream &accountStorage)
   {
       newAccount *account = new newAccount;
       accountStorage.pushToStore(account);
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 1):

2 problems:

1. `new_account(&accountStore);` is wrong, use `new_account(*accountStore);` to match the argument type.
2. `accountStore.push_back(account);` is wrong. `account` is type not object. Add some argument to the function.

Answer (score 0):

As answered here already, you need to use *accountStore and not &accountStore because the function takes a reference and not a pointer to a pointer (which is what you get from using & operator on a pointer).

the second problem is here:

```
template<class account>
inline void accountStream::pushToStore(account)
{
    accountStore.push_back(account);
}
```

you are declaring the function templated on the 'account' therefore account is a type, and what you are trying to do in the next line is push_back a type and not an object. 
the correct code would be:

```
template<class account>
inline void accountStream::pushToStore(account acct)
{
    accountStore.push_back(acct);
}
```

because account is the *type* while acct is an instance of the type account.

Comment: Yeah, after people have explained that it made me feeling kinda stupid! Guess I've got some reading to do.